# Craftsman Garage Door doesn't open with remote at higher temperatures

Tags: garage-door-opener

3 car garage (single and double doors), two 1/2 HP screw drive Craftsman openers, 15 years old.

The single works fine all the time, rain or shine, hot or cold, works prefect.

SAME remote, the double doesn't work when 'hot'

Live in Phoenix, no chance in the summer that is works.  It's currently February, when I leave work in the morning, I open with wall switch, get in car, back out, hit remote, closes fine (50 deg), high was 75, get home, sun is down, no dice, doesn't open.

To me it is time to get a new one, nothing makes sense to me other than a circuitry problem when things warm up.

Any last ditch ideas before I bit the bullet and get a new one??

Thanks!

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but have you tried a fresh good quality battery?

Comment: So this one remote opens both doors? Is it multiple buttons? If so, lets rule the remote out, and swap/program each door to the other button. See if the problem follows the button or the opener receiver. If problem follows the opener receiver, then it might have cold solder joints. Make sure any external antenna wires (if equipped) is not pinched on anything. Check all screw terminals are tight. If still an issue, see what warranty it has

Comment: i would clean, degrease, and regrease the track before i spent real money...

Comment: Yes, same remote, opens the single from many yards away regardless of temperature.  Switched buttons, follows the opener receiver.  Not the remote.  Checked antenna wires, looks good.  I pulled off cover at one point, didn't see anything obvious.  It's related to the remote circuitry, works fine from the wired wall switch.  Keypad has same issues as remote, good when cold, bad when hot.  No warranty, 15 years old.  What else can be checked/done for 'cold solder joints' ???  What would clean/degrease/regrease the track have to do with the remote??  It works great, that why I hate to replace...

Comment: Let me check something here - you are saying the wall switch ALWAYS works, but the remote and an external keypad do not work together when it is not working? Remove the wiring for they keypad. Let's isolate the keypad. Since it is outside? it could be weathered and shorting out or at least causing an issue on the same switched circut. See if the issue stays with the receiver, or works with the keypad disconnected

Comment: I'd try warming the remote in an oven during February. See if that makes it not work. You've replaced batteries and cleaned all contacts? After 15 years, things can get gungy. Perhaps the expansion of the remote box in the heat pulls a contact out of reach of the battery? Fit should be snug.

Comment: We could avoid a lot of questions back and forth, and people could have provided more qualified answers, if you had supplied a better description including a photo of the remote, a photo of the wall switch (switches), contol panel, the make and model of the product etc. It is not even evident from your post if the double garage door works with the wall switch when warm, or if the problem is only with opening, or also with closing. Sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

Had it fixed under home warranty, they replaced circuit board, working great now

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post your answer. Please also give yourself a check-mark so others know that this has a working resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Per our discussion above, and the troubleshooting steps you have performed, it makes sense that there is an open circuit. It is possible it is actually shorting out too. The fact that the wall switch always works, but another entirely separate switch AND the opener does not, tells me there is a bad path (lose wires, wet corrosion, loose parts etc), or a short (like the keyed switch) and its preventing the circuit from closing.

I would disconnect any inputs on the suspect receiver. Keep one switch handy, try each switched contact. Does it follow only one switched input? Also, inspect the screws and circuitry in the box. Pull the power, open it up, look for cold solder joints. [Example cold solder joint](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a1ec135f1bf0c3a70b3005221b7b6a72) This happens after time, usually on parts that didnt have enough solder to begin with, or when they were cooled to fast when originally assembled, or due to vibrations.

If you have this case, you can just resolder it, and be back in business.